# insert into and delete rows not in resultset

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a dynamically fetch resultset **(campaignList)** which I am inserting into a table.

```
foreach($campaingList as $campaignset) {

    $c_res = $campaignset->getData();

    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO campaigns (id, campaign_id, campaign_name) VALUES (". $data["id"] .", ". $c_res["id"] .", '". $c_res["name"] ."')";

}
```

This works as intended.

My question is, how can I delete old rows that are not in the currently fetched resultset?
If there for example are 200 rows in the table, and next time it will get 180 results in a request. How can I upon inserting, delete those 20 rows not found in the resultset **(campaignList)** ?

Comment: You can also delete every row before inserting!!

Comment: Can you add a column to flag up 'updated' rows? If so set this to 0 before the processing, set it to 1 on each insert and then delete any that are still 0. But might be easier to just delete all the records before inserting, as the insert will just add the records anyway. Depends why you are inserting and whether you want to update existing records.

Comment: First delete all rows from your table *campaigns* (DELETE FROM campaigns) and then perform your insert operation.

Comment: Arh.. Yeah.. of course... I overthinked it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all rows will do the trick.